# OpenCart - do I need to clean, strip, trim strings in forms?

Tags: php, opencart, trim

I have a simple question: do I need to worry about potential form injection issues in OpenCart forms or it's all taken care of by the developers? Do I need to clean, strip and trim all form input fields?

For example, if I modify the OC's existing contact form (information/contact):

```
$name = filter_var($this->request->post['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = strtolower(preg_replace( '((?:\n|\r|\t|%0A|%0D|%08|%09)+)i' , '', $this->request->post['email']));
```

Comment: This question lacks the information whether you are willing to post-process all the currently existing forms in OC or whether You are implementing a new feature. If a new feature You should take care of this of course by implementing appropriate validations and by escaping (and type-casting) of values that are being inserted into the database. Your question is similar to: *Do I need a knife for sliced onions?* - we do not know whether You have already a sliced onions or whether You want to have a sliced onions...

Comment: @shadyyx Please see I've edited my question above.

Comment: You can do this but here this is completely nod needed as values from contact form are only sent via email and not stored anywhere. With forms the only thing you should be afraid of is SQL(, JS, CSS) injection which really matters only with values being stored into the DB. Check few model classes and their methods to explore how string values are escaped (`$this->db->escape($value)`) or other types type-casted (e.g. `(int)$integer`).

Comment: with forms, the major issue is Bcc injections, so all escape characters should be removed as a minimum

Comment: I had few security seminars but never heard of Boc injections... Even google gave me no meaningful results when searching for it. Is it something You have just made up? :-)

Comment: @shadyyx If you haven't heard of that type of email header injection at those security seminars, I wouldn't go there again ;) Preventing the header injection is a must for any email form unless you want your form to be used for mass spamming. For example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428076/PHP-Mail-Injection-Protection-and-E-Mail-Validatio , http://www.arclab.com/en/webformbuilder/how-to-protect-php-email-form-against-mail-header-injection.html , http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html - this is just a quick google search

Answer (score 1):

All default forms in opencart are protected from SQL injection by opencart developer by doing proper escaping of user data. but if yoy are creating a form (or field) of your own, then you need to escape it yourself using

```
$this->db->escape($user_data);
```

this methods takes care of escaping irrespective of what db you are using (mysql,postegres etc)

they have done their part now you have to do your part.

P.S. you can see `catalog\model\account\customer.php` for an example

Comment: Yes, I can see they did that when they use the DB, however with the contact form they only removed php/html tags

Comment: @user665327 contact form are completely different things, contact forms are not gonna be saved on database so no sql injection possible, so the opencart just perform some validation like name should be between 3 to 32 characters etc you can see `validate`function contact controller for what validation it performs

Comment: @user665327 also concept of validation is different from sql injection prevention. validation just ensure very minimal things

Comment: So I take it the contact email form fields are not protected from Cc/Bcc injection and I have to take care of it myself

Comment: @user665327 i am not aware of cc/bcc injection but i guess if there is something like that then they must have done somthing to protect that. have a look at `system/library/mail.php` this is the file that handles all mails see if you find something there